# Dictionary of a protocol Swift 4

Tags: swift, dictionary, protocols, swift4

I have a protocol called playable which requires implementation of `func play()`. Class `Damage` and `DrawACard` both conform to the protocol

```
protocol Playable: class {
    func play(game: Game, value: Int) -> Player
}


class Damage: Playable, Hashable, Equatable {

    var hashValue: Int = 1

    static func ==(lhs: Damage, rhs: Damage) -> Bool {
        return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
    }

    func play(game: Game, value: Int) -> Player {
        // do stuff
        return game.activePlayer
    }
}

class DrawACard: Playable, Equatable, Hashable {

    var hashValue: Int = 2

    static func ==(lhs: DrawACard, rhs: DrawACard) -> Bool {
        return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
    }

    func play(game: Game, value: Int) -> Player {
        // do stuff
        return game.activePlayer
    }
}
```

My issue is the following:

```
class Card {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var cost: Int
    var description: String
    var target: Target
    var abilities: [Playable: Int]
    var cardType: CardType

    init(id: Int, name: String, cost: Int, description: String, cardType: CardType, target: Target, abilities: [Playable: Int]) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.cost = cost
        self.description = description
        self.cardType = cardType
        self.abilities = abilities
        self.target = target
    }
}
```

The 6th variable in the class `abilities` throws an error when I try to put a protocol as the key. It gives me: `Type 'Playable' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'`.

I want the abilities variable to have a key of an object that implements `Playable` and a value of `Int`, eg. `abilities = [DrawACard: 5]`

How can I go about doing that?

[image: Error]

Comment: What's the Int here (in `[Playable: Int]`) for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of mixing protocols with class inheritance is notoriously complicated. The answer to your specific issue is you can't directly, because if you make `Playable` conform to `Hashable`, you can't make an array of them.

The simplest solution is don't use a protocol here. Just make an abstract class. Swift isn't very good at abstract classes, but they will make most of these problems go away.

Given your specific case, I might also consider using an enum for `Playable` rather than a protocol. That would likely make things simpler.

From there, the solutions get a bit more complicated. For example, you could create a `ClassDictionary` along the lines of my [ClassSet](https://gist.github.com/rnapier/996dc97e6544fd243e1781e48513d970) experiment. Or you can build a type-eraser. But it gets ugly.

You could also consider switching from a class to a struct, and getting rid of the Dictionary, and just using an Array. If the point of the `Int` is a count, then just have multiple copies of the struct. If the point of the `Int` is a parameter (like "how much damage"), then that should be inside the `Damage` struct, not in a dictionary.

(Unrelated note, your hash values are very strange. They'll work, but this isn't how hashes are meant to function.)

As an example of where I'm going with this, I'm seeing something like:

```
protocol Playable {
    func play(game: Game) -> Player
}

struct Damage: Playable {
    let amount: Int

    func play(game: Game) -> Player {
        // do stuff
        return game.activePlayer
    }
}

struct DrawACard: Playable {
    func play(game: Game) -> Player {
        // do stuff
        return game.activePlayer
    }
}

struct Card {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let cost: Int
    let description: String
    let cardType: CardType
    let target: Target
    let abilities: [Playable]
}

// A card that inflicts one damage
let card = Card(id: 1,
                name: "Strike",
                cost: 1,
                description: "Strike 'em",
                cardType: CardType(),
                target: Target(),
                abilities: [Damage(amount: 1)])
```

This switched everything to immutable structs on purpose; I believe everything you're describing here are really value types.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the definition of the classes to this, so the classes inherit from a Hashable base class:

```
class PlayableClass: Hashable {

    var hashValue: Int = 0

    static func ==(lhs: PlayableClass, rhs: PlayableClass) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

class Damage: PlayableClass, Playable {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        hashValue = 1
    }

   ...
}

class DrawACard: PlayableClass, Playable {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        hashValue = 2
    }

    ...
}

class Card {
    ...
    var abilities: [PlayableClass: Int]
    ...

    init(id: Int, name: String, cost: Int, description: String, abilities: [PlayableClass: Int]) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not directly answer the question; however, it may be helpful to future readers of this question.

One idea is to use `AnyHashable` and use casting to get/set what you want.

Define your dictionary:

```
var abilities: [AnyHashable: Int] = [:]
```

Then create some methods to add/remove items in the dictionary.

```
func addPlayable<T: Playable>(_ myPlayable: T) where T:Hashable {
    abilities[myPlayable] = 0
}

func removePlayable<T: Playable>(_ myPlayable: T) where T:Hashable {
    abilities.removeValue(forKey: myPlayable)
}
```

Access the element like this:

```
func getValue<T: Playable>(_ obj: T) -> Int? where T:Hashable {
    return abilities[obj]
}
```

Or if you want to iterate the dictionary you could do this:

```
abilities.forEach { (it) in
    (it.key as? Playable)?.play(...)
}
```