# Extend @objc protocol with Hashable in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have an `@objc` protocol with this implementation:

```
@objc public protocol Document: class {
   var data: Data? { get }
   var image: UIImage? { get }

   func generatePreview()
}
```

And I'm trying to use it in a `[Document: Int]` dictionary, but naturally I get this error:

> Type 'Document' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'

The problem is that I don't know how to make it conform `Hashable`, since it is an `@objc` protocol and `Hashable` is only available in Swift. If I try to make it conform `Hashable`, I get this error:

> @objc protocol 'Document' cannot refine non-@objc protocol 'Hashable'

This protocol is used as a property in an `@objc` method, which I want to keep as an '@objc' method since it is part of a `@objc` delegate protocol.

This protocol looks like this:

```
@objc public protocol MyClassDelegate: class {

    @objc func methodOne(parameter: [Document: Int])

}
```

Any idea?

Comment: What's the purpose of declaring the protocol as `@objc`?

Comment: As I answered to @aaoli, it is used as a parameter in an `@objc` method

Comment: Well, ObjC doesn't really care about dictionary key types, so for `@objc` methods you may just use `NSDictionary`.

Comment: I know that I can use NSDictionary, but I'm asking this because I want to find a solution which allows me to use type safe dictionaries.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49479839/dictionary-of-a-protocol-swift-4/49479962#49479962 for another version of this problem. The short answer is: don't use protocols as keys in dictionaries. It never goes well and all the workarounds are a pain. The issue isn't `@objc`; it's protocols and Hashable.

Comment: Exactly, the problem it is not `@objc` but protocols and Hashable. I guess that there is not _good_ solution for this right now, or at least Swift is not prepared for it yet. I will give it a second thought and reconsider if the `Document` class should be a protocol or not. Thanks @RobNapier!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[AnyHashable: Int]` which is a type-erased hashable value.

I assume you have the protocol called Document:

```
@objc public protocol Document: class {
    var data: Data? { get }
    var image: UIImage? { get }

    func generatePreview()
}
```

And your protocol methodOne will be accepting [AnyHashable: Int]:

```
@objc public protocol MyClassDelegate: class {

     @objc func methodOne(parameter: [AnyHashable: Int])

}
```

Its kinda complicated question, after some research i agree with @Rob Napier

> don't use protocols as keys in dictionaries. It never goes well and
>   all the workarounds are a pain.

I might not answered perfectly but hopefully that should make the errors goes away.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot just remove the `@objc` from the method declaration because the protocol is used as a parameter in an `@objc` method.

Comment: @kikettas You mean you are using a optional func or just using a func as @ objc ? As I noted you’ll need to get rid of it in order to use Hashable ! Can update ur question with full details ?

Comment: I updated the question with more information that I think answer your question.

Comment: @kikettas kindly check the answer again !

Comment: @kikettas the `@objc` is not the issue as I said in my answer your working with protocols and the way your doing is not the correct one.

Comment: Okey, you edited the answer. I didn’t see it before. I guess that so far that should be the only way to solve it if I have to keep the `@objc`. I also agree with you that protocols should be avoided as keys in dictionaries. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167602/discussion-between-kikettas-and-aaoii).